# How do I configure the hostname for Rails ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, hostname, actioncontroller

I'm working on a fairly traditional forgot password email - I want to email the user a password change token embedded in a link that they can click on in order to change their password.  I'm emailing via the traditional ActionMailer.

If I use a normal link_to tag

```
<%= link_to "click here", :controller => foo, :action => 'bar', :token => token %>
```

I get a relative link - rather useless from an email.

If I add in

`:only_path => false`, then it errors saying I need to set `default_url_options[:host]`.  The ActionController docs imply that you do that by overriding the #default_url_options methods in your controller.  Surely there's a configuration option to tell Rails what it's hostname is without adding my own config file, parsing it, etc?

Comment: +1 for both the question and answer, this is so weird ... why is this setting on action mailer?

Comment: When sending an email, then there is no HTTP Request to take these values from.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`default_url_options` is available from `config.action_mailer` and should be set in your environment's configuration file.

For example, in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => 'www.yourdomain.com'
}
```

For local testing, modify `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
  :host => '127.0.0.1',
  :port => 3000
}
```

Then, assuming you have a named route called `forgot_password_login`, you can generate the login link URL in your mailer using something like this:

```
forgot_password_login_url(:token => 'a7s8q15sk2...')
```

Comment: not you have a "hanging" comma in your default_url_options hash. I would edit it but its a 1 char edit which is verboten on SO.

Comment: I feel like im losing my mind. This is not working for me

Answer (score 26):

You probably want to set :protocol => 'https' as well, btw.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { 
    :host => "portal.example.com", 
    :protocol => 'https' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the :protocol => 'https' pointer.  using 'portal.example.com' does not seem to work properly, at least with Devise mailers.  The resulting urls begin with 'https://example.com/' regardless of the subdomain).

Answer (score 4):

There is another alternative, as described in http://pivotallabs.com/how-i-leaned-to-stop-hating-and-love-action-mailer/

This solution has the advantage that it doesn't require any configuration (so less of a hassle), and works fine as long as you send emails from within controllers.

But if you plan on sending email without going through a controller (e.g. from command line or in response to another email), you need the static configuration.

Comment: That's a good tip, though I'm afraid I need the static configuration.  For some reason, I keep running into more and more processing that needs to happen outside of a web hit.

Comment: current link. http://pivotallabs.com/how-i-leaned-to-stop-hating-and-love-action-mailer/

Answer (score 0):

Setting `default_url_options` directly is deprecated in Rails 3.1. Use [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for) instead.

Add parameter `:protocol` to override default value (http), `:protocol => 'https://'`. This will create url starting with "https://..." instead of default "http://"

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I had the same issue as you did, but in unit tests (while following Michael Hartl's railstutorial). I had this line in my test.rb file, but that didn't help:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'example.com', protocol: 'http' }
```

I've also added another line like this to test.rb, and surprisingly this solved the issue

```
default_url_options = { host: 'example.com', protocol: 'http' }
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting default_url_options directly is deprecated in Rails 3.1

Use the url_for helper to create it:

```
<%= link_to "click here", url_for(:controller => foo, :action => 'bar', :token => token, :host => 'www.yourdomain.com') %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you just do

```
<%="click here", :controller => foo, :action => 'bar', :token => token, :host=>request.host -%>
```

Comment: request isn't available from within a mailer

Comment: Exactly.  I could pass it as one of the parameters to the email generation - but we just decided to move this particular email to being sent from our Application Server instead of the web front-end.  I think that means I need to make that custom config file that has the URL of the frontend website in it.

Comment: doh, missed the mailer part of it