# Gravatar default image not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I followed Railscast tutorial in order to use gravatar, it works for me but in case of a default image it did not shown it, what is the error with my code ?

```
def avatar_url(user)
        default_url = "#{root_url}images/user_avatar_small.png"
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
        "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"
    end
```

Also in case of using `"http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png?s=48&d=#{CGI.escape(default_url)}"` default image not showing and i am using devise gem

I checked browser inspector i found this error `GET http://i0.wp.com/localhost/images/user_avatar_small.png 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it is because of a missing host configuration in your app.

There are different options how to do this: [How do I configure the hostname for Rails ActionMailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798917/how-do-i-configure-the-hostname-for-rails-actionmailer) [How do I set default host for url helpers in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660172/how-do-i-set-default-host-for-url-helpers-in-rails)