# Getting full URL as displayed in browser URL bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku

I have a rails app where I want to send people an email when they sign up. The email has a link to their photos portal so they can get started adding photos, etc..

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email
    # ...

    link = photos_url  # => www.myapp.com/photos

    # ...
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I push my code to Heroku and run it live, that link doesn't generate as expected.

The `photos_url` returns the URL relative to the `localhost` and ends up generating `myapp.herokuapp.com/photos`, which is incorrect.

What's even stranger is that if I pause the code at that point with `binding.pry` and try to see what `photos_url` is returning, it correctly returns `www.myapp.com/photos` as expected.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? I'd hate to have to construct the URL myself from scratch, because that means I have to do it for every environment (`localhost`, `staging`, `production`, etc...)

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure the hostname for Rails ActionMailer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798917/how-do-i-configure-the-hostname-for-rails-actionmailer)

Answer (score 0):

ActionMailer isn't tied to the request/response cycle, thus it doesn't know what's the host the app is currently running on. Actually, emails are typically sent by some background worker processes which know nothing about the current request URL.

So to make it work you need to set the ActionMailer `default_url_options.host` option.

Add this into you `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.yourapp.com' }
```

Comment: Ah I see! So I used `ActionMailer` for this example since it's well known, but in my particular case I'm using a service called Mandrill which allows you to hit its api and it sends an email. The job is processed in the background by Sidekiq. The same problem still exists though - the background worker process (Sidekiq) doesn't know the host. Is there a more general way to get the host? It sounds like I have to manually configure it for each environment. Thanks!

Comment: In general you can set the hostname using a environment variable, e.g. `APP_HOST=www.foo.com`, and then pass that variable to the mail-api specific method (not-sure which one for Mandrill). Also it may happen that Mandril has the host set somewhere in its settings UI.