# ArgumentError in Rails::MailersController#preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, account, activation

I am working on 10 chapter in The Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, I am facing the issue regarding account activation

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

user_mailer.rb

```js
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"
    mail to: user.email
  end
end
```

account_activation.html.erb

```js
<h1>Sample App</h1>

<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>

<p>
Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

[image]

```
app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__2222007018826719766_70083837842380'
app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in `account_activation'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/799383/2057388

Comment: I tried to change the format of `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`, it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Add `default_url_options` to `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 3000 }
```

OR

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost', :port => 3000 }
```

Comment: `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

`

Comment: This is the default_url_options that I have set in the development.rb `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    :host => '127.0.0.1',
    :port => 3000
  }`

Comment: I stopped the server and then restarted it, it's working now. Thanks